# pyspark dataframe imported from mongo containing 6 M records has two records as string ('Error...' ) and the rest are of structytpe. cant write to s3

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I have to import data from mongodb using AWS Glue. i import the data in glue dynamic frame and conver glue df to spark df successfully. there is one field of struct datatype which gets it data from another server after it conducts a few tests in the form json object. one day their server went down and they were not able to perform their tests and our mongo server recorded their response as string - 'Error while checking the transaction for duplicate trueSample status'. out of a total of about 6 million records there are only two records of this type. this is causing my job to fail while writing this data as json to s3.
I want to know how can i put a condition that filters out these bad rows after the spark df is created from glue df.

```
df.filter(~spark_df.smplChnResp.startswith('Error while checking the transaction for duplicate trueSample status')).show()
```

getting error as

```
AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'startswith(`smplChnResp`, 'Error while checking the transaction for duplicate trueSample status')' 
due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`smplChnResp`' is of
struct<Respondent:struct<country:string,country_code:string,latitude:double,longitude:double,respondent_risk:int,respondent_ud:string,threat_potential:string,threat_potential_score:int,time_zone:string,weather_code:string>,Surveys:array<struct<country_mismatch:int,description:string,duplicate_initial_ud:string,duplicate_potential:string,duplicate_score:int,failure_reason:string,flag:int,survey_number:string>>> type.;;
\n'Filter NOT StartsWith(smplChnResp#1039, Error while checking the transaction for duplicate trueSample status)
\n+- LogicalRDD
```

Tried casting this column to string to filter out this row but still receiving error

```
df = df.filter(psf.col('smplChnResp').cast(pst.StringType()).contains('Error while checking') == False)

df.count()

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o422.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 6.0 (TID 19, 172.34.161.54, executor 1): com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast STRING into a StructType(StructField(Respondent,StructType(StructField(country,StringType,true), StructField(country_code,StringType,true), StructField(latitude,DoubleType,true), StructField(longitude,DoubleType,true), StructField(respondent_risk,IntegerType,true), StructField(respondent_ud,StringType,true), StructField(threat_potential,StringType,true), StructField(threat_pot
```